# Cannot select only columns with data

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$array = [];
while ($a < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $a);
    if (!$meta) {
        //error
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    foreach($row as $cell)
    $array[$b] = $cell;
    $b++;
}
    }
    $a++;
    $getColumns = mysql_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='OCN' AND `TABLE_NAME`='cpu'") or die(mysql_error());
$emptyColumns = array();

while($columns = mysql_fetch_assoc($getColumns)){
    $checkEmptyColumn = mysql_query("SELECT IF(". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] ." IS NULL or ". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] ." = '', 'empty', ". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] .") as ". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] ." from cpu") or die(mysql_error());
    $numEmptyColum = mysql_num_rows($checkEmptyColumn);
    if($numEmptyColum > 0){
        while($test = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkEmptyColumn)){
            array_push($emptyColumns, $test[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']]);
            //$emptyColumns[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']] = $test[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']];
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($emptyColumns);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am trying to select only columns that have at least one entry in them. If the entire column is NULL or empty, I don't want to display it. Unfortunately, I don't know what column names will be present. I figured the current method could pull each column name, and insert it by loop. It's still printing columns with completely null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `where` clause filters out rows, not columns.

Comment: Alright, how do I go about filtering columns? If no rows have data in a certain column, I don't want to display it.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: It's fairly easy to check if a certain column is empty. But if you don't know the column names, it becomes trickier.

Comment: Most people don't do this... so you're going to have to make it up as you go along. So: if I were to try to figure this out, I'd start with the question: how do you know a column is empty? Why don't you have a go at answering that, because it is what will spur the answer.

Comment: @TarynEast That's easy: `SELECT IF(columnName IS NULL or columnName = '', 'empty', columnName) as columnName from tablename` But he needs to know the column name for that.

Comment: I mean I do have the column names. I'm looping through the meta to find it. It works to print all the columns. I figured on my way to print them, I check if it has anything in it. Then I can decide to echo it or not.

Updated my answer.

Comment: Well - I think you can probably adapt @icecub 's  suggestion then... if you loop thorugh the column-names, you can then use each one to construct a query of the kind suggested to determine if the column is empty or not - then store whether or not to show it.

Comment: I'm working on an idea, but I need to know your database name so you can check it easily once done?

Comment: database name is OCN, table name is cpu

Comment: I might not understand the question - but isn't the simplest thing to do just to "select * from tbl", then as you loop over your mysql_fetch_assoc, loop over each key/value and check if it has a value?

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a big hit in performance? My goal: "I do not want to display columns that have no data in them. If there is a column that no row uses, do not display that column."

Comment: Ok this is what I've brewed up. It's just an idea and I have no idea if it'll work! Let me know if it does and I'll turn it into an answer: http://pastebin.com/f9f3PP0D

Comment: This is line is throwing an error: `$checkEmptyColumn = mysql_query("SELECT IF(". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] ." IS NULL or ". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] ." = '', 'empty', ". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] .") as ". $columns['`COLUMN_NAME`'] ." FROM cpu") or die(mysql_error());` Error string is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cpu' at line 1"

I also had to put backticks around the last COLUMN NAME (which is why it appears unformatted). Pretty much all my column names are just numbers.

Comment: Hmm I'll have to setup a test environment to check that out. Working on it

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. No rush.

@wrightee suggestion seemed to do something. It just printed "ID ID ID ID ID" over and over again. It's possible there's something there.

Comment: It's definitely working. There are 8 "ID" printed, and I have eight columns with data in them. I simply need fix my loops. icecub, you can hold off on your test environment. I don't want you to do unnecessary work if I figure this out. That is, unless you want to anyway (out of curiosity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long chat and finally understanding what exactly he wanted, I've revised my answer.

Basicly what he wanted to do was display only table columns that had data in them in one of the rows. So if a column was empty in all existing rows, it wouldn't  show.

Doing this with PHP and MySQL would probebly eat up a lot of cpu processing time, since he's got over 500 columns. Therefor I've done it with jQuery to achiev the same result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>OCN CPU PPD Database</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#main th').each(function(i) {
                var remove = 0;

                var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')')
                tds.each(function(j) { if (this.innerHTML == '') remove++; });

                if (remove == ($('#main tr').length - 1)) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    tds.hide();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Overclock.net CPU PPD Database</h1>
        <table id="main">
            <tr class="header">
                <?php

                $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
                if (!$conn) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                mysql_select_db('OCN');

                $getColumns = mysql_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='OCN' AND `TABLE_NAME`='cpu'") or die(mysql_error());
                $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM cpu') or die(mysql_error());

                while($columns = mysql_fetch_assoc($getColumns)){
                    echo "<th>". $columns['COLUMN_NAME'] ."</th>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

                while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<tr>";

                    foreach($data as $test){
                        echo "<td>". $test ."</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alright, I never got any further with that suggestion. I'll try this.

Comment: It should work just fine. Btw I rly do suggest moving on to `mysqli_*` or `pdo`. `mysql_*` is officially deprecated and to tell you the truth, it was a pain for me to revert everything to `mysql_*` :P

Comment: Also, if you don't need the column names in the array, uncomment the `array_push` and comment `$emptyColumns..` after that. The array keys will now just be 0,1,2,3 etc

Comment: Yeah, I don't need the array names to be column names. I had no clue it was deprecated. I'm just learning SQL on-the-fly here.

Comment: You've commented the wrong array xD Uncomment that one and comment `$emptyColumns[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']] = $test[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78142/discussion-between-tyler-montney-and-icecub).

Comment: Fantastic. He spent a good 2 hours figuring this out with me (and dealing with my own screw ups). Thank you again.

Comment: @TylerMontney No problem m8. You were patient and definitely not one of the "I want some programmer to make this for me because I have no idea about programming myself" type of users. It was nice working with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $checkResult = 'SELECT '.$meta->name.' FROM cpu WHERE '.$meta->name.'>'''' and '.$meta->name .' Is not null limit 1';
```

Comment: Prints all columns. I should note nearly all my column names are just numbers.

Comment: Is that what you want? It's an unpopular question and hopefully I don't need to do this.

Comment: No. According to my question, only columns that have data. If a column is unused by all rows, it should not be displayed. According to wrightee's suggestion, I'm making progress.